# Mysql query with Left Join is too very slow

Tags: sql, mysql, join, query-optimization

Query:

```
   select `r`.`id` as `id` 
     from `tbl_rls` as `r` 
left join `tblc_comment_manager` as `cm` on `cm`.`rlsc_id` != `r`.`id`
```

Both tables have 8k records but why is it very slow, taking 2-3 minutes and more sometimes?

OMG , this query makes mysql server down. Will get back to you peoples in a second :(

All peoples those suggested Indexing the columns are all Correct.
Yeh the query i wrote was silly and buggy. Thanks correcting me.

Comment: Are there indexes? If so, on which columns?

Comment: Both `id` columns should have indexes

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Consider also indexing your tables. We're running multiple left joins on a 1million+ record table that doesn't take more than a second or two to return results.

Comment: Holy hot damn was this the culprit. I went from 10 minutes to 0.9 ms. Any recommendation on a MySQL analysis tool that can tell you which indexes you should have on your database?

Comment: Indexing did the trick. query now runs in 233ms was previously 48s

Answer (score 13):

Do you really need the `!=` or is it meant to be `=`?

```
 select `r`.`id` as `id` from `tbl_rls` as `r` 
  left join `tblc_comment_manager` as `cm` 
on  `cm`.`rlsc_id`!=`r`.`id
```

This will select nearly the cartesian product of the 2 tables. (I guess around 60 million rows)

**Edit:** From the comment

> yes it is " != " to match tbl_rls.id
>   those are not in tblc_comment_manager

I think this is what you need if you want to use the `outer join` approach.

```
 select DISTINCT `r`.`id` as `id` from `tbl_rls` as `r` 
  left join `tblc_comment_manager` as `cm` 
on  `cm`.`rlsc_id`=`r`.`id
WHERE `cm`.`rlsc_id` IS NULL
```

Although my preference is usually

```
 select `r`.`id` as `id` 
 from `tbl_rls`
 as `r` 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(
          SELECT * FROM `tblc_comment_manager` as `cm` 
          WHERE  `cm`.`rlsc_id`=`r`.`id)
```

Comment: yes it is " != " to match `tbl_rls`.`id` those are not in `tblc_comment_manager`

Answer (score 4):

What do you want to select?

Use this query if you want to find tbl_rls records that haven't matching records in other table

```
select `r`.`id`
from `tbl_rls` as `r` 
left join `tblc_comment_manager` as `cm` 
    on  `cm`.`rlsc_id`=`r`.`id
where `cm`.`rlsc_id` IS NULL
```

Answer (score 4):

MySQL's [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/explain.html) might help you finding out what is going on.

Comment: this feels like it should be a comment

Answer (score 3):

You may need to provide more info.  But one thing I would try is reversing the order of your ON clause (because it's so easy):

`ON r.id != cm.rlsc_id`

*Edit: and you should put indexes on your PK (id) columns.*

But I think [this article might help you out](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/04/22/sql-server-better-performance-left-join-or-not-in/).

Basically it says that `NOT IN` takes less resources than `LEFT JOIN`.  A commenter in that article mentions using `NOT EXISTS` is best.

Also, I'm not sure this is accurate or not, but [this article says that `NOT IN` does a full table scan, and `NOT EXISTS` can use an index](http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2007/01/21/32/).

Comment: @JohnB For SQL Server 'NOT IN' and `NOT EXISTS` are more efficient (though care must be taken about NULLs for the first one). For MySQL I'm not sure what the recommendation is.

Comment: Additionally, others have pointed out the approach: `WHERE cm.rlsc_id IS NULL`

Comment: @Martin: someone who read **High Performance MySQL** might know the answer - http://www.amazon.com/High-Performance-MySQL-Jeremy-Zawodny/dp/0596003064

Comment: Neverthess, he has a few options that would take him 5 mins to test.  Arsheep, please post your results!

Comment: @Martin: when you make a column a PK in MySQL, does it automatically create an index for that column?  If not, create indexes for your PK columns Arsheep!

Comment: @JohnB - Yep quick test this end seems to say that you'll automagically get an index on the PK but I guess that might not help `tblc_comment_manager`

Comment: @Martin Smith: Depends on if the columns are [nullable](http://explainextended.com/2010/05/27/left-join-is-null-vs-not-in-vs-not-exists-nullable-columns/) or [not](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are wanting the r.id values that are not in the tblc_comment_manager table.

Use a Not In

select `r`.`id` as `id`
     from `tbl_rls` as `r`
where `r`.`id` not in (select distinct `cm`.`rlsc_id` from `tblc_comment_manager` as `cm`)